# RKEEL java issue in R

Tags: r

I'm want to run `CART_C` function from RKEEL package. I tried with this example program:

```
data_train <- RKEEL::loadKeelDataset("iris_train")
data_test <- RKEEL::loadKeelDataset("iris_test")

#Create algorithm
algorithm <- CART_C(data_train, data_test)
```

But i get this error:

```
    Error in super$setParameters(train, test) : 
  Clas-CART.jar doesn't exist under the defined path. Installation error;D:/temp/RtmpWGCj19/RLIBS_11fc85a976064/RKEELjars/exe/Clas-CART.jar
```

I think this is java error but I don't know how resolve it.

Anyone could help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the creators of the RKEEL package; first of all, sorry for the delay in answering you. In further cases, you can post the issues with the package in the issues place in the GitHub repository (https://github.com/i02momuj/RKEEL/issues).

I have updated the RKEEL package on CRAN (v1.3.1.), and the problem you addressed should have been solved. Up to date, it is available the source code, but in few days it should be compiled for Windows and MacOs. If you still find interesting using RKEEL, I hope this problem is no longer present, and if you find any other problem or errors, please let me know.

Again, sorry for the delay.
Regards.